# In Tears of the Kingdom, can you activate only certain devices attached to a vehicle?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In TOTK, I was doing the quest where you have to get the fella and his cart out of the hole. I attached the balloons and flame emitters to the cart, then added a fan.

When I activated them, they all turned on at once, which meant the cart hadn’t gained enough height before the fan pushed it into the side of the hole.

Is there a way I could have only activated the flame emitters first, and then the fan once it was at the desired height?

Comment: The easy (and yet maybe not obvious) way is to pick up the cart and move it further back from the rim before launching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only if you don't glue them.

When all devices are glued together they will always activate all at once.

However I successfully detached and reattached a device in air to change its orientation, on the very vehicle I was standing on.

That means you should be able to take the device with you on the vehicle, non-affixed, and then glue it when it's needed.

Comment: Also, you could try to somehow lock the fan in position without gluing it, like you do with the sign guy.

Answer (score 3):

There is one way (though I'm not sure it would be particularly applicable to your situation).

**Construct Heads**

The <strike>magic</strike> technology of the Construct Head is such that any attached parts *only trigger when an enemy comes within range*.

Less useful when trying to rescue a hornist, but more useful in ensuring your tank doesn't waste battery charge on your cannons and beam emitters when you're tank-ing it cross-country!

Comment: Thanks. I haven’t come across Construct heads yet.